# Generic with a type alias

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to create a mock function for async testing in TypeScript.
My function receives some data, and returns it when promise resolves.

I know I can type it like this:

```js
type Options<T> = {
  data: T;
};

export const mockApiCall = async <T>({ data }: Options<T>): Promise<{ data: T }> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({ data }), 100);
  });
};
```

But I would like to do it with a type alias in the function name, like this:

```js
type Options<T> = {
  data: T;
};

type MockData<T> = (options: Options<T>) => Promise<{ data: T }>;

export const mockApiCall: MockData<T> = async ({ data }) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({ data }), 100);
  });
};
```

But it returns the error `Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)`.

What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: I don't think you can, a _variable_ can't be generic.

Comment: Which variable? `mockApiCall` cant be generic?

Comment: Yes, there's no syntax for a let/const variable itself to have a generic parameter.

Comment: Interesting… thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The placement of your generic type parameter is wrong. You want a generic function (the type parameter to be on the function) not a generic type that happens to be a function. The difference is that a generic function has its type parameters decided when it is invoked. A generic type needs to have its type parameters decided when it is used.

```
type Options<T> = {
  data: T;
};

type MockData = <T>(options: Options<T>) => Promise<{ data: T }>;

export const mockApiCall: MockData = async ({ data }) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({ data }), 100);
  });
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzgHgCoD4oF4oBvAKCigBMBDYKgLiiwG4SBfFk0SKAWSQGMA1gBEaVAlGw4AFEnjJ0DOIlSZcASgJ4ACgCckAWwRoIGIpTEMsUVjg4QAHmCS7gUfqrcGBggIJgEAGEqABsQhj4hUVoJKjQQFH4oaXNqGNZNfDxScl0IYABXXRQoFAgAdyg9Q2MIaWk8tCQQgDcITOyycigTYCwEAwgkAuB6jqhG5raUi3T1ABooAEYABhX1FnIMlnYSIA)

Comment: Now I understand, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
type Options<T> = {
  data: T;
};

export const mockApiCall = async <T>({ data }: Options<T>) => {
  return new Promise<Options<T>>((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({ data }), 100);
  });
};
```

Comment: That's basically their first example...